# PHP Mysql Inter-process TLS

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, system-administration

I'm fairly new to the depths of sysadmin work, especially at this level, and have been tasked with establishing an 'industry standard' way of authenticating inter-process communication between the PHP application and MySQL database server.

I can't seem to find any reference in the mysql or PHP documentation. I've found an overwhelming amount of info in regards to standard TLS between PHP and Mysql for encryption purposes, however absolutely nothing in regards to mutual authentication (authenticating the PHP app inside Mysql). Is this possible with, or without custom plugins?

Comment: I would dare say, in practice, no one authenticates the PHP app from MySQL save for normal authentication where a user/password combination is setup in MySQL and that user is allowed certain roles. MySQL wouldn't be "aware" outside of that. Here is another similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881874/how-to-encrypt-connection-between-php-and-mysql-using-mutual-certificate-authent

Answer (score 2):

TLS only ensures that people can't strip your credentials "off the wire" using packet sniffing tools. It does nothing to ensure the identity of the device or application connecting to MySQL.

For that sort of thing you need an additional layer like SSH, or some kind of custom application that does verification before allowing a connection to MySQL via a proxy channel of some variety. That could be a complicated undertaking, and it's certainly *not* the industry standard.

The current standard is pretty simple:

- Restrict which machines have access to your MySQL server through aggressive firewall rules. Port 3306 should *never* be open to the general internet. At the very least it should be locked down to a handful of white-listed IPs or a network block like 192.168.x.0/24 for a portion of your internal private network.
- Use TLS or SSH tunnelling if you cannot ensure that the connections between the MySQL server and application are not secure. This is important if your servers are in different physical locations and you cannot ensure the connection is secure.
- Make your username and password credentials reasonably complicated and difficult to brute force. As these are configured at the application level, 60+ letter passwords are not a problem. Make them large and completely random. You'll never need to type these in by hand. Use a configuration file or password manager.

If you have additional concerns **get an audit done** by a reputable security firm to be sure your strategy is sound.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that are in common use.  First, if the PHP app properly checks the mysql server's certificate, then you know the mysql server is who it claims to be.  That authenticates the mysql to the php.  Then, when you send a database password, you've authenticated the php app to the mysql server.  You used different approaches in each direction, but achieved mutual authentication.  That by far is the most common approach and it does meet the definition of mutual authentication.

A less common approach is to use [client certificates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-secure-connections.html); see the text starting "To require that a client certificate also be used."
By using the --ssl-cert and --ssl-key arguments to mysql's command line (and similar connection arguments from php), you can provide a client certificate to the server.  The server's certificate is used to authenticate the server to php, and the client certificate to authenticate php to the server.